# Convert fixed length number to decimal .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a import txt file with number in this format:

```
00000000003000
00000000009500
00000000003000
00000000002000
00000000000500-
00000000001500-
00000000003000-
00000000003000-
00000000009500-
```

This is the number which last 2 chars are the decimals. (minus sign if negative value) 
For example:

```
00000000003000 = 30.00
00000000000500- = -5.00
```

Is there a function to convert this string to decimal and save my time writing one?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you'll have to write one or find a free library were someone else already had to convert numbers like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
 String source = "00000000001500-";

 Decimal result = Decimal.Parse(source, 
   NumberStyles.Any, // NumberStyles.Any includes trailing signs
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 100.0M;
```

If you want (for some fields, values) *four* decimal places just change `100.0M` to `10000.0M` for these fields:

```
 Decimal result4 = Decimal.Parse(source, 
   NumberStyles.Any, // NumberStyles.Any includes trailing signs
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) / 10000.0M;
```

Comment: Nice solution. But watching another fields in the same file. I found that there is numbers with 4 decimal places. For example: 00000000150000- = -15.00

Comment: in that case (*four* decimal places) you have to decide when apply *two* and when *four* digits schema. One of the soultions: `if (Math.Abs(result) >= 100) result \= 100M`;

Comment: @YuriMorales But how do you know how many decimal places there are? The "fixed length decimals" have the same size, so how can you tell the difference?

Comment: This is the best solution for 2 decimal places. But watching the file, there are some fields with 2 and 4 decimal places. So I take Luaan 2nd solution and modified to work with decimal place desired.

Comment: Luaan because is the same decimal for the whole field... I mean there is multiple decimal places in diferents fields. (Price with 2 decimals, cost with 4 decimals)...

Comment: ...Then just change `/100.0M` to `/ 10000.0M` on the field(s) where you want 4 decimal places

Answer (score 3):

Nothing that would target your exact scenario specifically - the trailing `-` being quite uncommon in particular.

I'd just use something like this:

```
public static decimal Parse(string val)
{
  return (val.EndsWith("-") ? -1M : 1M) 
         * decimal.Parse
           (
             val.Substring(0, 12) 
             + "." + val.Substring(12, 2), 
             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
           );
}
```

Or, using `NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign`:

```
public static decimal Parse(string val)
{
  return 
    decimal.Parse
      (
        val.Substring(0, 12) 
        + "." + val.Substring(12), 
        NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like 2nd solution, modified function parameters to add decimal places and this work perfect: "val.Substring(0, 14 - decimalPlace)
                  + "." + val.Substring(14 - decimalPlace),"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decimal.Parse` with a custom format provider with the proper [`NumberFormatInfo.NumberNegativePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbernegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx)that appends the minus => `formatProvider.NumberNegativePattern = 3;`:

```
var formatProvider = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Clone();
formatProvider.NumberNegativePattern = 3;
var numbers = File.ReadLines(yourFilePath)
    .Select(l => l.TryGetDecimal(formatProvider))
    .Where(n => n.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.Value / 100.0M);
```

Used this extension to parse the string to decimal in a LINQ query:

```
public static decimal? TryGetDecimal(this string item, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null, NumberStyles nStyles = NumberStyles.Any)
{
    if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    decimal d = 0m;
    bool success = decimal.TryParse(item, nStyles, formatProvider, out d);
    if (success)
        return d;
    else
        return null;
}
```

If you want the sum of all your decimals you can use `Enumerable.Sum`:

```
decimal sum = numbers.Sum(); // 0
```